# Error using offset argument in an intercept only model in lrm function R, from rms package

Tags: r, logistic-regression, offset

I cannot fit an intercept only model with an offset term using the lrm function from rms. The equivalent model can be fit with glm. I cannot find anything about this on the internet. Reproducible example below. Any help appreciated!

```
### Generate data
###

## Load rms
#install.packages("rms")
library(rms)

## Set seed
set.seed(1)

## Generate event probabilities
p.true <- runif(1000, 0.2 , 0.8)

## Generate binary outcome
state1.bin <- rbinom(1000, 1, p.true)

## Crete dataset with outcome, and the logit of the event probabilities
data.raw.temp <- data.frame("state1.bin" = state1.bin, "p.true.logit1" = log(p.true/(1-p.true)))


### Fit an intercept only model, using the logit of the event probabilities as an offset
###

## GLM attempt 1
glm(state1.bin ~ offset(p.true.logit1), data = data.raw.temp, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
## lrm attempt 1
lrm(state1.bin ~ offset(p.true.logit1), data = data.raw.temp)
## lrm attempt 2
lrm(state1.bin ~ 1, offset = p.true.logit1, data = data.raw.temp)
```

GLM attempt 1 sucessfully fits the desired model

```
Call:  glm(formula = state1.bin ~ offset(p.true.logit1), family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = data.raw.temp)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
   -0.02642  

Degrees of Freedom: 999 Total (i.e. Null);  999 Residual
Null Deviance:      1270 
Residual Deviance: 1270     AIC: 1272
```

lrm attempt 1 gives the following error

```
Error in lrm(state1.bin ~ offset(p.true.logit1), data = data.raw.temp) : 
  object 'nact' not found
```

lrm attempt 2 gives the following error

```
Error in fitter(X, Y, offset = offs, penalty.matrix = penalty.matrix,  : 
  formal argument "offset" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do it using `lrm`, but you can use `lrm.fit`.

```
with(data.raw.temp, lrm.fit(y = state1.bin, offset = p.true.logit1))
```